# VBA - Creating filter criteria from nested query

Tags: vba, if-statement, nested

I am trying to create a filter criteria which checks the data and if it matches then it will print the data.
I have the following and I get type mismatch error. for cTest.
I have also tried the following (without quotes- but then it returns false): cTest = (InStr(getName(iVar), a1) > 0)

Is there an easier way to create the filter criteria.

If fields a1, a2, and a3 are filled in the criteria should check that the value contains all there before returning anything.

```
  Dim cTest As Variant

If a1 <> "" Or a2 <> "" Or a3 <> "" Then
If a1 <> "" Then
  If a2 <> "" Then
   If a3 <> "" Then
   'Value entered in 1,2,3
    cTest = "(InStr(getName(iVar), a1) > 0) And (InStr(getName(iVar), a2) > 0) And (InStr(getName(iVar), a3) > 0)"
    End If
    ' Value entered in 1,2
    cTest = "(InStr(getName(iVar), a1) > 0) And (InStr(getName(iVar), a2) > 0)"
      End If
      '(Value entered in 1 only
   cTest = "(InStr(getName(iVar), a1) > 0)"
ElseIf a2 <> "" Then
  If a3 <> "" Then
    'Value entered in 2,3
    MsgBox ("2nd, 3rd value entered")
  End If
   ' Value entered in 2 only
ElseIf a3 <> "" Then
    'Value entered in 3 only
     MsgBox ("3rd value entered")
Else
     ' no value entered
     MsgBox ("no value entered")
End If
End If

For iVar = 1 To Phrases.MaxIndex()


        If (cTest) Then
        'We want this one
        .Cells(irow, 1).Value = getName(iVar)
        irow = irow + 1
      End If
    Next iVar

  End With
```

Comment: I would like to know if this is the way too.  Never think the condition can be dynamically generated like this.

Answer (score 0):

how about using simple joining of AND & OR conditions?

```
Sub testing()

    If ((a1 <> "" And InStr(getName(iVar), a1) > 0) Or a1 = "") And _
    ((a2 <> "" And InStr(getName(iVar), a2) > 0) Or a2 = "") And _
    ((a3 <> "" And InStr(getName(iVar), a2) > 0) Or a3 = "") Then
        ' the wanted one
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: would this only provide a result if a1, a2, and a3 are filled in? maybe I am missing something

Comment: No , the part
    or a1=""<-- enables the condition to pass if a1 is "" , same applies to a2,a3